# How can I change the layout of a WordPress child theme page?

Tags: html, wordpress, layout, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress. I have Woocommerce website. The product page is a Kaffa child theme. It has an image and under the image it has form of buttons and inputs.

I want to change layout of this page to be image on right and on the left will be the form.

How code is now:

```
<div class="row centeres">
  <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
    image & form 
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"> image</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">form</div>
</div>
```

How I can do that

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how to override a WordPress theme or modify a child theme. That's been covered extensively elsewhere. It's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a float: right; to your image container. This will ultimately depend on how your theme is set up:

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images.woocommerce-product-gallery {
    float: right;
}
```

On the Kaffa demo site this is the result (assuming again that this is the same theme you mention):

https://snipboard.io/TNSmVv.jpg

Comment: that don't seem to work .. should i apply the property on figure container ?

Comment: You can give that a try. Without seeing the entire code (and how your theme is laid out) we can not know for sure. As stated I simply went to the demo site for the theme you mentioned and it works there (as seen in the screenshot). Sorry I can not help more without knowing the whole bit of code but if you are using their child theme and have not modified core files or hooks - it should work.

Comment: You are most welcome - if you still have issues try adding more information to the original post (i.e. actual code from the entire container - google console is your friend)

Comment: i solved it using flexbox

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using flexbox:

```css
row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

div.col-md-6 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"> image</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">form</div>
</div>
```